# How can I align numerical and angle values in a table using siunitx?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, siunitx

As described in DIN 461, units such as "Degree", "Minute" or "Second" should stay with their numerical value when labeling the tics of a coordinate system. I have no proof, but I think that this rule also makes sense for tables. Normally, I always write the unit apart of the values but for angles, I would like to keep the unit in place.

My MWE shoes that case for the unit `\degree`.

```
\documentclass[]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage[
per-mode=symbol-or-fraction,
locale=DE,
sticky-per
]{siunitx} 

\begin{document}
\begin{table}   
\centering
\sisetup{table-number-alignment = center, }
        \begin{tabular}{|r|S|S|}
        \hline 
        \textbf{Test:} & {Test1} & {Test2}\\ 
        \hline 
        \hline 
        $\alpha_1$&\ang{17.0}&\ang{18.0}\\ 
        \hline
        $\alpha_2$&\ang{17.00}&\ang{18.00}\\ 
        \hline
        $\alpha_3$&\ang{17} & \ang{18}\\ 
        \hline  
        $T_{\text{t},0}/\si{\kelvin}$& 293.15 & 393.15\\ 
        \hline
        $p_{\text{t},0}/\si{\pascal}$& 80000,00 & 90000,00\\ 
        \hline              
        \end{tabular}   
    \caption{Test table}\label{tab:tt}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

For such tables, I can't get the numbers aligned properly. As you can see, the first three rows differ in their decimal alignment and non is equal to the last two rows (which work well).

[image: Table with ill aligned angle values]

---

It should be a second question, but if anybody has an idea on getting the cell width automatically adjusted to big numbers, that would be great, too.

Comment: I would advice 'dividing through': `$\alpha_{1}/\si{degree}$`, _etc._ You then only align numbers on decimal markers. Moreover, I've no idea wheat DIN 461 is on about: degrees are units like any other.

Comment: I did that before but didn't like it. The dividing looks strange for angles and even more if angles like `\ang{;;-3}` appear. Same for `10^h` for a time point which should be differed to `\SI{10}{h}` for a time range. DIN 461 is a German standardization mentioning exactly that case, which disturbs me in tables, as rule for coordinate systems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

[image]

The trick is done with the `table-space-text-post = \si{\degree}`
and `table-align-text-post = false` options. I had to split the `\ang` commands in the number and symbol part.

```
\documentclass[]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage[
per-mode=symbol-or-fraction,
locale=DE,
sticky-per
]{siunitx} 
\usepackage{booktabs}


\begin{document}
\begin{table}   
\centering
\sisetup{table-figures-decimal = 3, 
  table-figures-integer = 5,
  table-space-text-post = \si{\degree}}
        \begin{tabular}{l
            S[table-number-alignment = right, table-align-text-post = false]
            S[table-number-alignment = right, table-align-text-post = false]}
          \toprule
        \textbf{Test:} & {Test1} & {Test2}\\ 
        \midrule
        $\alpha_1$&17.0\si{\degree}&18.0\si{\degree}\\ 
        $\alpha_2$&17.00\si{\degree}&18.00\si{\degree}\\ 
        $\alpha_3$&17\si{\degree} & 18\si{\degree}\\ 
        $T_{\text{t},0}/\si{\kelvin}$& 293.15 & 393.15\\ 
        $p_{\text{t},0}/\si{\pascal}$& 80000,00 & 90000,00\\ 
        \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}   
    \caption{Test table}\label{tab:tt}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Damn!, I was trying to be faster than Joseph :-)

Comment: That's beautiful and exactly what I meant. Just a pity, that I will have to edit a lot of angle values which I all typeset to `\ang{}`. It's a great work around but will always need adaption for the other mentioned cases.

Comment: Two more questions to your result. Can I move everything behind `S` to the `sisetup{}`-section? Why do I have to tell the length of mantissa and decimal? Isn't that quite uncomfortable especially when reading values out of a data file?

Comment: And one more: you changed my `table-number-alignment = center` to `table-number-alignment = right`. However, I can't see a difference between your and my case (when toggled in your MWE)

Comment: @LaRiFaRi: I think that the problem of overlapping was fixed when I tell the length of the numbers. I prefer to align numbers to the right, but aligning them to the decimal separators; I think makes them look centred.